# Book: groups leaving Earth for space, return to an Earth reduced to tribalism

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of a book, or the author. The story centers around groups leaving the planet for interstellar points. At some time in the future a group returns to find that Earth has rejected space travel and and other technological advances, reverting to essentially tribalism. The travelers struggle with cultural reference.

I am not sure how old this story is, perhaps 10 or 15 years.

Comment: Hi there! :) could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] into your answer? Like, which language was it written in - was it a translation? Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Answer (score 1):

This is "I Still Call Australia Home" by George Turner. I read it in *The Science Fiction Century* edited by David G. Hartwell,published in 1997. I no longer have this book so I can't quote from it, but here's the synopsis I wrote for myself:

A relativistic ship returns to Earth after a centuries-long voyage. Human society has changed so much, reverted to agrarian, that they find they are not at all welcome.